# Docker: Connection from inside the container to localhost:port Refused

Tags: docker, connection, containers

I'm trying to insure the connection between the different containers and the localhost address (**127.0.0.1**) used with port **8040**.( My web application container run using this port.)

```
 root@a70b20fbda00:~# curl -v http://127.0.0.1
 * Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1/
 * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
 *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
 * connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
 * Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
 * Closing connection 0
 curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

This is what I get when I want to connect to localhost from inside the container

```
root@a70b20fbda00:~# curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8040
* Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1:8040/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8040 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8040: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8040: Connection refused
```

About **iptables** in each container:

```
 root@a70b20fbda00:~# iptables
 bash: iptables: command not found
```

Connection between the container is good

```
root@635114ca18b7:~# ping 172.17.0.1
PING 172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.253 ms
--- 172.17.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
root@635114ca18b7:~# ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
root@635114ca18b7:~# ping 172.17.0.3
PING 172.17.0.3 (172.17.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.149 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.180 ms
--- 172.17.0.3 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.149/0.164/0.180/0.020 ms
```

Ping the 127.0.0.1:8040

```
root@635114ca18b7:~# ping 127.0.01:8040
ping: unknown host 127.0.0.1:8040
```

What I need to do in this case?

So the Global image that there is two containers ,

- The first container contains a **tomcat server** that deploy my **web application** and it turnes perfectly.
- The second is a container that need to connect to the web application 
  URL. **http://127.0.0.1:8040/my_app**

Comment: what kind of network are you using in both containers?

Comment: Thank you for your response, the two containers are in a virtual machine that use as network connexion  **bridget**.

Comment: use host connection

Comment: Sorry but you are talking about **Nat** as network connexion.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you will have to use `docker run --network host IMAGE:TAG` for achieving the desired connection

further read [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/#procedure)

example:-

```
docker run --network host --name CONTAINER1 IMAGE:tag

docker run --network host --name CONTAINER2 IMAGE:tag
```

inside container - CONTAINER2 you will be able to access other container as host CONTAINER1

And for accessing the service you will have to do CONTAINER:

Comment: Ok i will delete the container and re-run it again using this command and i will let you know about the output.
Thank you.

Comment: remember hostname will be the container name

Comment: what you means by the **hostname will be the container name** ? you mean that i should update the content of the hosts file under /etc/hosts

Comment: No need to add in hosts file

Comment: docker run --network host --name=my-container --link mysql:mysql  -p 8040:8080 -d my_container
I get this error:
Error response from daemon: conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior. ------> so i should delete the link part ?

Comment: Yeah remove that

Comment: Yes now each container can reach the other one, i fixed the port number in the dockerfile so i didn't use -p port:port and also i didn't use the --link option

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided, looks like there are two containers. If these two containers are started by docker without `--net=host` then each of them get two different IP addresses. Say your first container got `172.17.0.2` and the second one `172.17.0.3`.

In this scenario each container gets it's own networking stack. So `127.0.0.1` refers to it's own networking stack not the same.

As pointed out by @kakabali, it's possible to run the containers with host network, sharing the networking stack of the host.

One of the other options is to use the actual IP address of the first container in the second one.

`second-container# curl http://172.17.0.2`

Or another option is to run the second container as the sidekick/sidecar container sharing the networking stack of the first one.

`docker run --net=container:${ID_OF_FIRST_CONTAINER} ${IMAGE_SECOND}:${IMAGE_TAG_SECOND}`

Or if you use `links` correctly:

`docker run --name web -itd ${IMAGE_FIRST}:${TAG_FIRST}
docker run --link web -itd ${IMAGE_SECOND}:${TAG_SECOND}`

Note: docker `--link` feature is deprecated.

Another option is to use container management platforms which take care of service discovery for you automatically.

PS: You cannot ping an IP address on a different port. For more info, click [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port).

Comment: Thank you for your response, now i understand more about how containers contacting each other.